# Multi-Tiered ComboBox Binding in DataGrid

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, telerik

The control is for a telerik RadGridView, but a solution for a DataGrid is also acceptable.

I'm trying to figure out how to bind the itemssources for a few comboboxes in my datagrid.  The scenario is as follows:

In each row, there are 3 comboboxes.

ComboBox #1 - Displays the current days of the week, eg. Mon Oct 21, Tues Oct 22 [...], Sun Oct 27.

ComboBox #2 - Displays the JobNumbers that are available based upon the day selected in ComboBox #1.

ComboBox #3 - Displays potential SubJobNumbers for a selected JobNumber.  Sub Job Numbers can be used by more than one JobNumber so this table is in a bridge....

Let me know if you need additional information from me to help clarify the situation!

[image: Database Schema]

Code Behind:

```
var dayOfWeekCollectionViewSource = (CollectionViewSource)this.FindResource("DayOfWeekCollectionViewSource");
        dayOfWeekCollectionViewSource.Source = this.currentWeek;
var jobNumberCollectionViewSource = (CollectionViewSource)this.FindResource("JobNumberCollectionViewSource");
        jobNumberCollectionViewSource.Source = this.jobNumbers;

    var subJobNumberCollectionViewSource = (CollectionViewSource)this.FindResource("SubJobNumberCollectionViewSource");
        subJobNumberCollectionViewSource.Source = this.subJobNumbers;
```

Page Resources:

```
<CollectionViewSource x:Key="DayOfWeekCollectionViewSource"
                          d:DesignSource="{d:DesignInstance System:DateTime, CreateList=True}" />
<CollectionViewSource x:Key="JobNumberCollectionViewSource"
                          d:DesignSource="{d:DesignInstance DataAccess:JobNumber, CreateList=True}" />
<CollectionViewSource x:Key="SubJobNumberCollectionViewSource"                           d:DesignSource="{d:DesignInstance DataAccess:SubJobNumber, CreateList=True}" />
```

Telerik RadGridView:

```
<telerik:RadGridView x:Name="TimesheetLineItemGridView"
                             Grid.Row="0"
                             Grid.Column="0"
                             Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                             ItemsSource="{Binding}"
                             AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                             ShowGroupPanel="False"
                             RowIndicatorVisibility="Collapsed">
    <telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
        <telerik:GridViewCheckBoxColumn Header="Approved"
                                        DataMemberBinding="{Binding Path=ApprovedDateTime, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource approvedCheckboxConverter}}" />
        <telerik:GridViewComboBoxColumn Header="Day"
                                        ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource DayOfWeekCollectionViewSource}}"
                                        DataMemberBinding="{Binding Path=LineItemDate}" />
        <telerik:GridViewComboBoxColumn Header="Job Number"
                                        ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource JobNumberCollectionViewSource}}"
                                    DataMemberBinding="{Binding Path=JobNumber}" DisplayMemberPath="Code" />
        <telerik:GridViewComboBoxColumn Header="Sub Job Number"
                                        ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource SubJobNumberCollectionViewSource}}"
                                    DataMemberBinding="{Binding Path=SubJobNumber}" DisplayMemberPath="Code"  />
    </telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
</telerik:RadGridView>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: `Let me know if you need additional information from me to help clarify the situation!` - Yes. Please post the code you already tried, and how it didn't work, and what are the expected results. Otherwise you'll get closevotes quickly here.

Comment: Here's what I've got thus far.  I can get the ComboBoxes to populate the information from my whole list, but I need a way to filter the options down, as the user would drill down to them.